# SINON Stub findall and scope at same time

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sequelize.js, sinon, loopback4

I'm trying to mock my sequlize db call
Below is the example

```
it('mock db call', async() => {
    sinon.stub(DBNAME, 'scope').resolves()
    sinon.stub(DBNAME, 'findAll').resolves(dbDetails)
    const res = await func1();
    sinon.assert.match(res, dbDetails);
})
```

function `func1` is as below

```
const func1 = async () => {
    const getData = await DBNAME.scope(
      'includeEverything',
    ).findAll();
    return getData
}
```

Does anyone knows how to stub `scope` and `findAll` at same time.

i'm getting error as below

`TypeError: models_1.DBNAME.scope(...).findAll is not a function`

I'm trying to test func1 and stub  'scope' and 'findAll'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sinon.stub().returnThis()` to stub the method chain calls.

`index.ts`:

```
import { DBNAME } from './db';

export const func1 = async () => {
  const getData = await DBNAME.scope('includeEverything').findAll();
  return getData;
};
```

`db.ts`:

```
export const DBNAME = {
  scope(arg) {
    return this;
  },
  findAll() {
    return this;
  }
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { func1 } from '.';
import { DBNAME } from './db';

describe('75529424', () => {
  it('mock db call', async () => {
    const dbDetails = {};
    sinon.stub(DBNAME, 'scope').returnsThis();
    sinon.stub(DBNAME, 'findAll').resolves(dbDetails);
    const res = await func1();
    sinon.assert.match(res, dbDetails);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  75529424
    ✓ mock db call


  1 passing (7ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      75 |      100 |      50 |   71.43 |                   
 db.ts    |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |   33.33 | 3-6               
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```